# Como fazer minha aplicação no React-native identificar nosso idioma?

Tags: react-native

Quando insiro um texto, ex:

```
<Text>Maçã</Text>
```

ele não reconhece! sei que é a meta utf8, mas não sei onde inseri-la!
Grato desde já!

Answer (score 0):

Pelo o que entendi, você quer internacionalizar sua aplicação, correto?
Você vai precisar de um plugin, como o :

https://github.com/react-community/react-native-languages

```
npm install --save react-native-languages
react-native link react-native-languages
```

Uso :

```
import RNLanguages from 'react-native-languages';

// Current device language
console.log('language', RNLanguages.language);

// User preferred languages (in order)
console.log('languages', RNLanguages.languages);

// Listening for languages changes (on Android)
RNLanguages.addEventListener('change', ({ language, languages }) => {
  // Do languages related things…
});
```

Tem também o https://github.com/stefalda/ReactNativeLocalization

```
npm install react-native-localization --save
react-native link react-native-localization
```

E pode usar criando componentes para a localização

```
// ES6 module syntax
import LocalizedStrings from 'react-native-localization';

// CommonJS syntax
// let LocalizedStrings  = require ('react-native-localization');

let strings = new LocalizedStrings({
 "en-US":{
   how:"How do you want your egg today?",
   boiledEgg:"Boiled egg",
   softBoiledEgg:"Soft-boiled egg",
   choice:"How to choose the egg"
 },
 en:{
   how:"How do you want your egg today?",
   boiledEgg:"Boiled egg",
   softBoiledEgg:"Soft-boiled egg",
   choice:"How to choose the egg"
 },
 it: {
   how:"Come vuoi il tuo uovo oggi?",
   boiledEgg:"Uovo sodo",
   softBoiledEgg:"Uovo alla coque",
   choice:"Come scegliere l'uovo"
 }
});
```

E chamar

```
<Text style={styles.title}>
  {strings.how}
</Text>
```

Comment: Olá, Amigo! Primeiramente, muito obrigado por tentar me ajudar!
Eu criei um projeto novo, instalei o react-native-languages, seguindo o primeiro exemplo que você me passou...
acessei a pasta do projeto e linkei!
não sei se essa é a forma correta, mas não funcionou! talvez eu tenha feito da maneira errada, se puder me ajudar sendo mais específico, fico grato!

Comment: O que houve? Usou o mesmo exemplo? Não saiu nada no console? E o segundo exemplo? Sugiro tentar ele, é mais simples

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido!
A configuração do meu editor, não estava para **utf8!**
Assim que setei para **utf8**, os caracteres apareceram.
Obrigado pela ajuda!